# C++11 packaged_task doesn't work as expected: thread quits and no output

Tags: c++, multithreading, future, packaged-task

I've this code snippet:

```
#include<future>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  cout << "---------" << endl;
  packaged_task<int(int, int)> task([](int a, int b){
    cout << "task thread\n";
    return a + b;
  });
  thread tpt(move(task), 3, 4);
  cout << "after thread creation\n";
  future<int> sum = task.get_future();
  cout << "before join\n";
  tpt.join();
  cout << "after join\n";
  sum.wait();
  cout << "after wait\n";
  cout << sum.get() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

It only printed

```
---------
after thread creation
task thread
```

then hang for about 2 seconds, and ends. I don't see my packaged_task function execute. It didn't print `"after join\n"` and `"after wait\n"`

Why my program ended unexpectedly, how to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're moving the packaged task into the thread and then trying to get the future object from the moved-from task which no longer has any state. For me this throws an exception: https://godbolt.org/z/Gh534dKac

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::future_error'
>
> what():  std::future_error: No associated state

You need to instead get the future from the task *before* moving it into the thread:

```
...
future<int> sum = task.get_future();
thread tpt(move(task), 3, 4);
cout << "after thread creation\n";
...
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xhzKxh96K